# Can I determine whether the file descriptor is available before calling write()?

Tags: macos, posix, system-calls, fwrite

I am now working on **Mac OS X**, and I make myself a **MYFileHandle** class. This class implements file operation like **NSFileHandle** by POSIX system call (like *read()*, *write()*, etc), but would provide more status values.

But I met a problem. If the file descriptor was set to a remote disk in local network (for example, a shared folder of a Windows system). When the connection was lost, the `write()` system call will **block**.

In this situation, is there any way to check the availability of the given file descriptor before calling the "*write()*" function? Or can I make the "*write()*" returns immediately after its operation is failed instead of blocking?

Comment: Isn't it dependant on how remote file system was mounted?

Comment: Maybe not. In Mac OS X, all remote volumes are mounted in its /Volume directory. I don't know if there are any other mounting methods...